# ReSharper Code Inspection Additions

Tags: c#, resharper, static-analysis

Is it possible to extend resharper code inspection/annotations to handle cases you know staticly are correct?

For example, I have utility function I know satisfy certain conditions, such as:

```
    static public bool IsValid(double? d)
    {
        return d != null && IsValid(d.Value);
    }
    static public bool IsValid(double d)
    {
        return !Double.IsNaN(d) && !Double.IsInfinity(d);
    }
```

So this ensures a nullable has a value, and I'd like the "Possible System.InvalidOperationException" inspection not to fire for something like:

```
    if (Utils.IsValid(nullableValue))
    {
        DoSomethingWith(nullableValue.Value);
    }
```

Sure I could suppress the inspection/etc, but is it possible to extend the static typing to indicate that this would actually ensure the value is non-nullable?

(I suppose a related but overly general question is should I be using another static typing check instead of resharper that might handle it, but I won't ask for fear of being overly broad!)

Comment: I haven't used it myself but you could try using the [Contract annotation feature](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/contract-annotations-in-resharper-7/).

Comment: Looks very promising!  Looking through it now to see what the right annotation might be.  Much appreciated!

Comment: That's very useful in general, I'll definitely use those, but I don't see a way to express that it checks for a constraint on the value passed to it.  (That is, it checks input and output constraints, but I don't see a way to express that under a given return value something would be true about the parameter passed to it.)

Comment: Actually, that's exactly the ticket!  Referenced here (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html), you can do [ContractAnnotation("d:null => false")] and it works like a charm!  (If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'd love to accept!)

Comment: You found the solution yourself! Just post it and accept it :)

Comment: Well thank you regardless!  These annotations have made my world just a little brighter!  (I suppose the resharper folk deserve some credit as well, but I'm gonna direct most of it your way!)

Comment: Thanks, that's really kind of you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Daniel's suggestion, resharper supports a good deal of [annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html) to assist with inspection.

Specifically, via the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html) what we're looking for here is something like:

```
    [ContractAnnotation("d:null => false")]
    static public bool IsValid(double? d)
    {
        return d != null && IsValid(d.Value);
    }
```

Which does the trick perfectly, and the static check works beautifully.

Love that resharper!